# How to compile netcat-openbsd for debian etch?

Tags: linux, debian, compile, netcat, openbsd

I tried:

```
apt-get install netcat-openbsd
apt-get source netcat-openbsd
```

It complains:

```
E: Couldn't find package netcat-openbsd
E: Unable to find a source package for netcat-openbsd
```

Then, I tried:

```
wget ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/netcat-openbsd/netcat-openbsd_1.105.orig.tar.gz
tar -xzf netcat-openbsd_1.105.orig.tar.gz
cd netcat-openbsd-1.105
make
```

It complains:

```
Makefile:6: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I also tried the following on Jessie:

```
apt-get build-dep netcat-openbsd
apt-get source netcat-openbsd
tar -czf nc.tar.gz netcat-openbsd-1.105
cat nc.tar.gz | nc -l 80
```

And then on Etch:

```
wget 192.168.1.101
tar -xzf index.html
cd netcat-openbsd-1.105
make
```

It complains:

```
netcat.c:99:24: error: bsd/stdlib.h: No such file or directory
netcat.c:100:24: error: bsd/string.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [netcat.o] Error 1
```

You don't say? Let me trick you:

```
cd /usr/include
mkdir bsd
for i in *; do ln -s ../$i bsd/$item; done
cd /root/netcat-openbsd-1.105
make
```

Now it says:

```
socks.c:41:32: error: bsd/readpassphrase.h: No such file or directory
socks.c: In function 'getproxypass':
socks.c:120: error: 'RPP_REQUIRE_TTY' undeclared (first use in this  function)
socks.c:120: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
socks.c:120: error: for each function it appears in.)
socks.c:120: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
make: *** [socks.o] Error 1
```

Yes, I DO need it on Etch, and I need the BSD's -d option. I am running out of ideas, any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of : `apt-cache policy netcat-openbsd` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: `netcat-openbsd` did not exist in the ancient times of `etch`. So:

`W: Unable to locate package netcat-openbsd`
`deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib`

Comment: Searching for the name of the missing file on http://packages.debian.org (you should always start there in the cases like yours) suggests the missing file *for the current stable release* is provided the package `libbsd-dev`.  Unfortunately, it was not available back then for Etch as your next stop <https://archive.debian.net/etch/libsd-dev> suggests.  So it appears like you will first need to backport this package from Jessie (or later), install it and then re-try backporting `netcat-openbsd`.

Comment: Please note that only grabbing the "orig" tarball might not be quite OK for backporting because this obviously won't provide you with any debianization patches.  The correct approach is to install `devscripts` and then use `dget` (not `wget`, you see) to fetch the `.dsc` file of the source package (the link to it is right there on the same package's page) -- this program will contain all the three files comprising the requested Debian package. You'll then need to call `dpkg-source -x that_file.dsc` to unpack the "orig" tarball and apply debianization patches.

Comment: Well, may be this is not really needed for you at *this* stage but it's something to continue with if you'll decide to do a proper backport (to provide an uninstallable package).